# Unexpected behaviour in TLS handshake

Tags: tls

I used in client side,

```
/* signature algorithm list */
(void)SSL_CTX_set1_sigalgs_list(ctx, "RSA+SHA512");
```

Expected behaviors is that client will only accept the server certificate which has digital signature algorithm **SHA512withRSAencryption**.

but here, client accepts the server certificate which has digital signature algorithm SHA256withRSAencryption also.

Why ?